# Selecting list values based on matrix binary values?

Tags: python, numpy, oop, matrix, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to map elements of a binary matrix to a list of integers. It needs to loop over each row of the matrix, if the value is 1 an item from the corresponding list is chosen and if the value is 0 no item is chosen. The end goal is to have a vector containing the sum of each row of corresponding values.
For example:

```
listOfNums: [1,2,3,4,5]

m1= [[1,0,1,1,1] 
[0,0,0,0,1] 
[1,0,0,0,1]]

>>>[13,5,6]
```

Here is what I have tried so far however I keep getting index errors

```
  def corrspondingVal(self, x):
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    return [self.nums[i] for i in range(x) if x[i]] 

  def sumPerRow(self):
    v = np.apply_along_axis(self.correspondingVals(self.matrix1), axis=1, arr=self.matrix1)
    return v
```

(self.matrix1 is a (10,5) matrix of binary values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one short way, although the multiplication may be expensive.

```
np.sum(m1 * list, axis=1)
```

Even better is

```
np.dot(m1, list)
```

Comment: or even `np.dot(m1, list)`

Answer (score 0):

Without `numpy`:

```
listOfSums = [ sum(num for idx,num in enumerate(listOfNums) if row[idx]) for row in m1 ]
```